# What is the proper way to punctuate a question and answer within the same statement?

Tags: punctuation, questions

How do I punctuate a statement in which both the question and answer are included?

For example: Will budgeting alone fix the problem, No!

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Can't you use a question mark instead of the comma, splitting it into two sentences? Also, you could use a tag question: *Budgeting alone will not fix the problem, will it?* It's common for people to speak as if ignoring the question mark, and that is how people subtitle movie dialogue, etc.—connecting two separate thoughts with a comma. However, it's not standard English.

Answer (score 3):

A rhetorical question is still a question. An answer to a rhetorical question is still an answer. Therefore:

> Would budgeting alone fix the problem? No!